# rails3.2.13 alternate edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

Need: two forms for editing for a two-step process.

```
resources :evaluations do
  collection do
    get ':id/change', :action => 'change'
```

controller

```
def change
  @evaluation = Evaluation.find(params[:id])
```

edit has link to the change action

```
<%= link_to 'Modify initial data', 'change' %>
```

Form gets following tag, identical to the edit form tag

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/evaluations/53" class="edit_evaluation" data-validate="true" id="edit_evaluation_53" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Failure: submitting leads to no action.

How can I make invoke update attributes?

One thought was to have change action lead to :

```
def update_changed_variables
   @evaluation = Evaluation.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   if @evaluation.update_attributes(params[:evaluation])
```

but that fails as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is essentially a Wizard.  Check this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked) out.

**Update**
Slice your form into two (or more) forms, separate the form attributes as required.  Add the same number of actions in your controller.  Set the form path to submit data to the appropriate action.

Here's an example:

**form 1:**

```
<%=form_for @object, :action => 'form1_action'%>
  < form1 attributes >
```

**form 2:**

```
<%=form_for @object, :action => 'form2_action'%>
 <form2 attributes >
<%end%>
```

**controller:**

```
form1_action
 save object
 redirect_to new_form2 if saved
end

form2_action
 save object
 redirect_to object_show (or another form) if saved
end
```

Comment: That is an avenue.  However it seems a lot of meta- thinking/work, particularly for validations. Since I only have to invoke update_attributes, I assume their is a more concise solution

Comment: There sure is, you can slice your form as required, have separate actions to update that particular part of the form and move back and forth; aka reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the set-up works.

```
def update_changed_variables
```

is not needed.  Rather, painfully simple...

the change.html.erb simply calls the form partial, which calls the same

```
<%= form_for @evaluation [...]
```

and thus invokes updates_attributes

I swear it was not running earlier.  restart webserver et al...
|homer_simpson_moment|